# build xml dynamically based upon input with xslt1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

hello want to create an xslt that creates this xml dynamically.

Output should be:

```
<Products>
    <Product productCode="SQUARE-BLUE-EXTRA-A-10-MAY" messageTag="SquareMessage"/>
    <Product productCode="SQUARE-RED-EXTRA-B-20-JUNE" messageTag="SquareMessage"/>
    <Product productCode="TRIANGLE-BLUE" messageTag="TriangleMessage"/>
</Products>
```

this is my input xml

```
<Root>
    <Object>
        <QuoteLineItems>
            <Object>
                <Product2Id>
                    <ProductCode>SQUARE</ProductCode>
                </Product2Id>
                <QuoteLineItems>
                    <Object>
                        <Product2Id>
                            <ProductCode>BLUE</ProductCode>
                        </Product2Id>
                        <QuoteLineItems>
                            <Object>
                                <ServiceDate>MAY</ServiceDate>
                                <attributes>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_VOLUMEPERCENTAGE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Volume percentage</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>10</value>
                                    </Object>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_TYPE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Type</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>A</value>
                                    </Object>
                                </attributes>
                                <Product2Id>
                                    <ProductCode>EXTRA</ProductCode>
                                </Product2Id>
                                <QuoteLineItems/>
                            </Object>
                        </QuoteLineItems>
                    </Object>
                    <Object>
                        <Product2Id>
                            <ProductCode>RED</ProductCode>
                        </Product2Id>
                        <QuoteLineItems>
                            <Object>
                                <ServiceDate>JUNE</ServiceDate>
                                <attributes>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_VOLUMEPERCENTAGE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Volume percentage</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>20</value>
                                    </Object>
                                    <Object>
                                        <attributeuniquecode>ATTR_TYPE</attributeuniquecode>
                                        <attributedisplayname>Type</attributedisplayname>
                                        <value>B</value>
                                    </Object>
                                </attributes>
                                <Product2Id>
                                    <ProductCode>EXTRA</ProductCode>
                                </Product2Id>
                                <QuoteLineItems/>
                            </Object>
                        </QuoteLineItems>
                    </Object>
                </QuoteLineItems>
            </Object>
            <Object>
                <Product2Id>
                    <ProductCode>TRIANGLE</ProductCode>
                </Product2Id>
                <QuoteLineItems>
                    <Object>
                        <Product2Id>
                            <ProductCode>BLUE</ProductCode>
                        </Product2Id>
                    </Object>
                </QuoteLineItems>
            </Object>
        </QuoteLineItems>
    </Object>
</Root>
```

input xml is expandable so it has to be dynamic.
Later i also want to remove Products with duplicate productCode attributes.

i've asked a similar question before but i came up that is this the solution i need. altough, i do not know how i can make the xslt build the xml dynamically.
anyone can help?

Comment: What is the logic that determines the order of values in e.g. `productCode="SQUARE-BLUE-EXTRA-A-10-MAY"`? The different `-` separators strings seem to occur in a different order in the source so you will need to explain what determines the order in the result.

Comment: the first three "SQUARE-BLUE-EXTRA" need to be in that specific order. the last 3 "A-10-MAY" are just randomly chosen by me. they can be in a different order. but once an order has been chosen it has to be in that order for every productCode. but if i'm correct in the source they are in the same order.

Comment: The last `Product` in the desired result sample doesn't even have three items, only two `productCode="TRIANGLE-BLUE"`. How deeply nested can the input be, is that as in the input sample restricted to a certain level or can it be arbitrary? What determines which level is mapped to a `Product`, collecting the code from ancestors and children or descendants?

Comment: aha. The first 2 are mandatory. last 4 are optional but they all come together. so it's 2 or 6.

Comment: basically the options are gave are the only possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I think in XSLT 2 or 3 you could `string-join` the values but in XSLT 1, to populate that attribute, you need to push them through a template (or you could also pull in by for-each):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Root">
    <Products>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Products>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="QuoteLineItems/Object[not(QuoteLineItems/Object)]">
    <Product messageTag="{Product2Id/ProductCode}Message">
        <xsl:attribute name="productCode">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::Object/Product2Id/ProductCode | ServiceDate | attributes/Object/value" mode="product-code-value"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </Product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="product-code-value">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">-</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26n7/1

Of course, if you want to eliminate duplicates later, it seems questionable to concatenate values into an attribute value if the different items are needed for the key as breaking up the attribute values is more difficult than working with node-set, but perhaps that is a different problem.

Comment: oh wow, but here you take every attribute/object/value. i only want ATTR_VOLUMEPERCENTAGE and ATTR_TYPE. i have more attributes in my original input. (i adapted the input i gave here) sorry

Comment: also, when i have a deeper nested input structure (so the 6 instead of 2) the attribute messagetag in my output will be EXTRAmessage altough it has to be SquareMessage

Comment: and the order of attributes is not correct. productCode="SQUARE-BLUE-MAY-10-A-EXTRA" should be productCode="SQUARE-BLUE-EXTRA-MAY-10-A"

Comment: i've posted an answer with some adaptions Martin. if you could take a look, i'm almost there

Comment: You said the order did not matter so I just used the document order. But as you have posted an answer of your own you should accept it and raise follow-up problems in separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

i adapted your xslt.

still a few things i can't get my head around

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <Products>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Products>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="QuoteLineItems/Object[not(QuoteLineItems/Object)]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Product2Id/ProductCode='EXTRA'">
                <Product messageTag="{../../../../Product2Id/ProductCode}Message">
                    <xsl:attribute name="productCode"><xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::Object/Product2Id/ProductCode | ServiceDate | attributes/Object[attributeuniquecode='ATTR_VOLUMEPERCENTAGE']/value | attributes/Object[attributeuniquecode='ATTR_TYPE']/value" mode="product-code-value"/></xsl:attribute>
                </Product>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Product messageTag="{../../Product2Id/ProductCode}Message">
                    <xsl:attribute name="productCode"><xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::Object/Product2Id/ProductCode | ServiceDate | cpq_ServiceEndDate | attributes/Object[attributeuniquecode='ATTR_VOLUMEPERCENTAGE']/value | attributes/Object[attributeuniquecode='ATTR_TYPE']/value" mode="product-code-value"/></xsl:attribute>
                </Product>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="product-code-value">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">-</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product messageTag="SQUAREMessage" productCode="SQUARE-BLUE-MAY-10-A-EXTRA"/>
    <Product messageTag="SQUAREMessage" productCode="SQUARE-RED-JUNE-20-B-EXTRA"/>
    <Product messageTag="TRIANGLEMessage" productCode="TRIANGLE-BLUE"/>
</Products>
```

the value 'EXTRA' is at the end and i want it as 3rd value in the productCode.
so it has to be: SQUARE-BLUE-EXTRA-MAY-10-A

another issue i'm struggling with is. in my original message the date is not just a month but a real date in this format: '2020-06-01'. is there a way i can remove the dashes - from the dat only. so it does not interfere with the dashes in productCode attribute?